# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" in exercise from "Learn C the Hard Way"

Tags: c

So I'm following this lesson from the [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html) tutorials and I'm a little stuck.

When I try to compile I get this:

```
cc -Wall -g    ex19.c object.o   -o ex19
ex19.c:81:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ex19.c:81:2: warning: (near initialization for 'RoomProto.move') [enabled by default]
ex19.c: In function 'Map_move':
ex19.c:91:7: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
ex19.c: At top level:
ex19.c:140:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ex19.c:140:2: warning: (near initialization for 'MapProto.move') [enabled by default]
make: *** [ex19] Error 1
```

From what I understand, this error occurs b/c the function returns `next` when it expects a `void` return type. But I thought `void *foo()` meant returning a void pointer.

Here's the code:

```
Object RoomProto = {
    .move = Room_move,
    .attack = Room_attack
};

void *Map_move(void *self, Direction direction) {
    Map *map = self;
    Room *location = map->location;
    Room *next = location->_(move)(location, direction);

    if(next)
        map->location = next;
    return next;
}
```

Room Struct:

```
struct Room {
    Object proto;

    Monster *bad_guy;

    struct Room *north;
    struct Room *south;
    struct Room *east;
    struct Room *west;
};
```

How can I fix this error? I tried to change the return type, but ended up getting another error instead.

As far as I can tell, I copied the code in the tutorial char for char, so unless I made a mistake, the tutorial is incorrect.

Comment: Which lines are 81, 91 and 140?

Comment: also show the struct definition of `Room`, and explain what `move` is. The line featuring `move` is unconventional.  (edit: link to book includes the relevant info)

Comment: There's no error. This function is supposed to return a `void *` (i.e., a pointer to something unspecified), and it does exactly that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ah, apologies. Added in line numbers.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker there are errors as shown by the compiler output

Comment: Yes, but not what you think they are. Do you have a macro "_"? Perhaps the Room_move function is not returning a pointer as it should?

Comment: @TeneCursum I'm going to guess that you typed out the stuff from the book, and left out the first `*` from the line `void *(*move)(void *self, Direction direction);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb added in the room struct as well. The link to the tutorial also has all the code if you need more context

Comment: The hard way indeed.  Line 91 looks like a train wreck.

Comment: OK , will vote to close as typo :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja I can see why they did it although it's hard to approve of anything that uses `_` as a macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MattMcNabb helped me find the answer

Line 13 in `object.h` file was:

```
void *(move) (void *self, Direction direction);
```

instead of:

```
void *(*move) (void *self, Direction direction);
```